# Joint proportion test on binomial panel data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, z-test

I'm trying to run a hypothesis test on panel data, where in each period $t_i$ an event $X\in \{0,1\} $ either does or does not occur for each of the entities in the panel.

I'm trying to determine whether the event $X$ is more likely to occur at $t_{i}$ if it has already occurred in $t_{i-j}$.

At first I thought a proportion test was appropriate, where I take the proportion of entities that ever have the event occur, $k_0$, over the total population, $n_0$, and compare it to to those that ever have the event *re*occur, $k_1$ over those that had it occur at least once, $n_1=k_0$. It's my understanding that this is the correct way to set this up, but I'm not sure if I have it right.

But now I'm wondering if it makes more sense to do some sort of joint proportion test for each period $t_i$. Here, I would have a vector of the above proportions for each of these periods:

- $n_{0_i}$ is the sum of entities that haven't yet had the event occur in $t_i$,
- $k_{0_i}$ are the entities that have the event occur in any period $t_j, j>i$ but that have not yet had the event occur in $t_i$
- $n_{1_i}$ are those that have the event occur in period $t_i$
- $k_{1_i}$ are those where the event reoccurs in any period $t_j, j>i$ and that had the event occur in period $t_i$

Alternatively, I was thinking of summing over each of these vectors for each $t_i$ and sticking with the standard proportion test (meaning that while $k_1$ and $n_1$ would be the same, $k_0$ and $n_0$ would be much larger).

Comment: I might think to model the the probability p_nt of the event occurring in subject n at time t using logistic regression:   
X_nt ~ bernoulli(p_nt);   
logit(p_nt) = alpha + beta1*(did the event occur at t-j) ...

You could then add additional covariates for different lag times, for continuous or categorical effects of time period, random effects of individual, etc. as appropriate.

Comment: I thought of doing a logit (and probably will at some point), but I wanted to start from a hypothesis test as it doesn't require specifying a model (the needs of this project dictate that such judgement calls be minimized).

Comment: Also, would I use `clogit()` in R to achieve this?

Comment: A hypothesis test of the sort you proposed DOES require specifying a model!!!

Comment: Use `glm()` to achieve this, or `lme4::glmer()` for the model with random effects.

Comment: I think I would want fixed effects, no? I'm not sure how to prep the data for this kind of regression. Do I want each subject to have `i` observations for each period, where the subject identifier is my strata? I'm assuming that, in the simplest setup, the dependent variable captures whether the event occurs (so 1 or 0 in a given period) and I'd have a an independent variable that is 0 in the first period for each subject, and becomes 1 in the period after the event first occurs and remains so for all later periods. Do I have that right?

Comment: Yup, it would make sense to use an indicator variable of that form, provided that you want to test for an effect of whether previous occurrence of the event (at any time in the past) alters the probability of future occurrence.  But let's distinguish two possibilities:  it could be that some individuals are inherently more likely to display the event than others.  Imagine now that previous occurrences of the event do NOT affect the probability of future occurrences.  Continued below...

Comment: Continued from above:   Nevertheless, we are more likely to observe the event in individuals where it has already occurred--not because their probability went up, but because the first occurrence identifies them to us as "high-probability individuals."  Imagine that some individuals have constant has probability .01 per timestep (regardless of their past history), and others have constant probability .7   Now if we see an event once in an individual, we are much more likely to see it a second time in the same individual, because that individual is probably of the p=0.7 type. Continued below...

Comment: Continued from above: Therefore, it is important to control for among-individual variablility in absolute probabilities (if that is logically plausible in your study system).  If you have long timeseries for each individual and few individuals, then you might think about a fixed effect of individual.  But if you have a fair number of individuals, then a random effect of individual is probably (this is a very wishy-washy use of "probably" since I can't see your data or know the study system) going to be a more efficient estimator of the effect you're interested in.